# SQL: Matching multiple columns value

Tags: sql

I have a database set up so that the username (username) and id (id) are stored in the members table.

I have another table that records reports and I record each column in the table (fid), who reported it (rid) and who they were reporting (id) which both match to the user's id in the members table.

How could I get a query to pull the username for both the rid and id?

My current query is

```
SELECT selfreport.fid, selfreport.rid, 
       selfreport.id, members.username as username
FROM members, selfreport
WHERE members.id = selfreport.id
ORDER BY fid
```

but this only gets the username for who they were reporting.  How can I get it to pull the username for both?

Comment: I'm kinda confused with what you want, can you show us an example of the desired output ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to join to your members table twice. Try something like this:

```
SELECT      selfreport.fid,
            selfreport.rid,
            selfreport.id,
            COALESCE(WhoReported.username, 'Not Specified') AS WhoReportedUN,
            COALESCE(ReportedTo.username, 'Not Specified') AS ReportedToUN
FROM        selfreport
LEFT JOIN   members WhoReported ON WhoReported.id = selfreport.id
LEFT JOIN   members ReportedTo ON ReportedTo.id = selfreport.rid
ORDER BY    fid
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to join `members` twice:

```
SELECT selfreport.fid, 
       selfreport.rid, 
       selfreport.id, 
       m1.username AS ReportToUsername, 
       m2.username AS ReporteeUsername 
FROM   selfreport 
       INNER JOIN members m1 
         ON m1.id = selfreport.id 
       INNER JOIN members m2 
         ON m2.id = selfreport.rid 
ORDER  BY fid
```

Since you were doing an implicit join in your original query, I believe `INNER JOIN` will suit you well. However, if it's possible to have null values in `selfreport.id` or `selfreport.rid`, you should use `LEFT JOIN` instead.

Comment: `inner join members m2 on m1.id = selfreport.rid` should be `inner join members m2 on m2.id = selfreport.rid`

Comment: That was a typo @Johan, it's fixed now, thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 2):

Do not use implicit SQL '89 joins they are an antipattern.
Use explicit join syntax instead.

```
SELECT s.fid, s.rid, s.id, m1.username as username, m2.username as rusername
FROM selfreport S
INNER JOIN members m1 ON (m1.id = s.id)
INNER JOIN members m2 ON (m2.id = s.rid)
ORDER BY s.fid
```

If `id` or `rid` is optional, use a left join.

```
SELECT 
  s.fid, s.rid, s.id
  , COALESCE(m1.username, 'nobody') as username
  , COALESCE(m2.username, 'nobody') as rusername
FROM selfreport S
LEFT JOIN members m1 ON (m1.id = s.id)
LEFT JOIN members m2 ON (m2.id = s.rid)
ORDER BY s.fid
```